# Does upgrading one Firebase project to a paid plan also benefit other projects?

Tags: android, firebase

I have two projects on Firebase console under one account which are running on Spark plan. I want to upgrade one of the project's plans to Flame. If  I upgrade one project's plan, will the other projects  benefit of the upgraded plan as well or do I need to update the plan for each project separately?

Comment: Hi & welcome to stackoverflow ! Your question is hard to read, you should try to reformat it, so that it gets an answer quicker. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some pro tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Firebase the plan applies to each individual project. When you upgrade one project, the upgrade applies only to that project. There is no concept of shared quota between projects, so if you want multiple projects to have increased quota, you will need to upgrade each of them individually.